# VB.NET equivalent of vbHighlight and vbHighlightText from VB6? (.Backcolor/.ForeColor of a TextBox)

Tags: vb.net, textbox, vb6, background-color, vb6-migration

What would be the .NET equivalent fore/back color to replace the following VB6?

```
 With TextBox1
    .BackColor = vbHighlight
    .ForeColor = vbHighlightText
 End WIth
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

> Contains system colors, system brushes, and system resource keys that correspond to system display elements.

```vb
With TextBox1
  .BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
  .ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
End WIth
```